# Saving elements to database with $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to save dynamically created elements in my application.js file to the database. Would the code look something like this?:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: { title: 'oembed.title', thumbnail_url: 'oembed.thumbnail_url'}
});
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Assume that `oembed.title` and `oembed.thubnail_url` hold the values I want to save, and that `title` and `thumbnail` are the database columns.

Comment: Is this rails? Please be more specific and retag. If it is rails, please elaborate more on your model + controller.

Comment: do you really need to know my model and controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem I see is your data is strings. Get rid of the ' quotes

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: { title: oembed.title, thumbnail_url: oembed.thumbnail_url}
});
```

Comment: do I need a `url:` setting? What should that be?

Comment: Yeah. That must point to your service on the server. Are you familiar with the concept of asynchronous client calls?

Comment: I understand it theoretically, that it's a way to retrieve data from the server without a page reload, but I have trouble actually implementing these things. What do you mean by the service on the server?

Comment: Ohh ok sorry, Ruby on Rails. I have a video controller and model, and i'm not sure where the url should be pointed to. The create method url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you need to incorporate some user-supplied data into the new DB object - otherwise, it would be way easier to just create it from Rails.

If you're using *entirely* user-supplied data, you can use the `serialize()` method (use hidden fields for server-generated stuff):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/whatever',
    data: $('#MyForm').serialize(),
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Or you could use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) - it'll let you easily combine user-supplied data with server-generated data.  For example:

```
$('#MyForm').ajaxForm({
    //Hardcoded/server-generated stuff goes in here
    //(and will be added to the data from the form inputs):
    data: {title: oembed.title},
    type: 'POST'
});
```

The `ajaxForm()` function will set up the form and its defaults, and sends an AJAX call when the user hits the submit button (see also: `ajaxSubmit()`).

On the Rails side, everything should work exactly the same as if the user had submitted the form normally (though you might want to just respond with a status code/message - no call for a redirect or page render).

Hope this helps!

**PS:**  From your example, it looks like you might be able to use `data: oembed` in your AJAX calls.  This will submit *all* oembed's attributes...

Comment: hmm Here's my specific case: All I accept is a video URL from the user and add that url as a link to the view. Then I use the embedly API to find that link and turn it into an embedded video, thumbnail, and title. I also want to allow the user to edit the title, so I need to save that. I like your first option, but I'm not sure which `url` to pass. Also, I'm assuming everything I want to save that is not the video url should be a hidden field, but I'm not sure. Also, finding the links and turning them to videos takes a long time with Embedly, so I may want to do it differently.

Comment: also if I use `.serialize()` on the form, how does the form know what the values are of the hidden fields whose values are generated dynamically by jQuery?

Comment: @Justin - The `url:` option in the AJAX call is just the URL for the create action in your app; the video URL will come from the user in an input in your form.  You could have another text input for them to override the default title (mark it as optional?).  Hidden fields would be used to store info that was generated by your server at the time the page loaded - I can't think what that would be, but I mentioned it just in case...

Comment: @Justin - And `.serialize()` will just make a string from _all_ the inputs inside your form.  It'll build something like this: `?input1-name=input1-val&input2-name=input2-val`.  It won't differentiate between hidden/regular fields, nor will it know if a value was user- or server-generated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this answers my question though. I can already save the video URL the normal way. I'm just concerning with saving the elements that are generated dynamically by the Embedly API that don't come directly from the form.

Comment: @Justin - Ah.  Slappy's answer is more what you're looking for, then.  (Although if the conversion process is as slow as you say, you may want to do it asynchronously from your server via something like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) - it'll be more reliable than using JS from the user's browser).  Cheers!

Comment: delayed_job looks cool! I asked about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320548/how-should-i-be-using-delayed-job