# How should I be using delayed_job?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I've read the [docs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/README.textile), but I'm unsure how to integrate it into my application. Currently I have a user input a video url, I take that url and make it a link in the view. Then I use the Embedly API to find that link and replace it with an embedded video, thumbnail, and title. However, this process takes a bit too long, so I'm thinking of using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to speed up this process. How should I go about doing this? I'd like to also save the dynamically generated title returned from the Embedly API into my database so users can edit it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DJ](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) jobs can be anything. Did you read the DJ tutorial? If you have a Video model, use an after_save callback that calls a function, say, generate_video_widget(), via DJ, like so:

self.delay.generate_video_widget()

It's up to you to implement generate_video_widget() to do the things you need it to do.

Comment: This doesn't really help me. Should generate_video_widget() be in the model? How does it interact with my code in `application.js` that finds the link and changes it to a video?